# Youtube iframe api Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, kentico

On our website which is built in Kentico we have embedded a youtube video, as follows:

```
 <div class="youtube">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%# Eval("YouTubeId") %>?autoplay=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;controls=1&amp;loop=0&amp;playlist&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;iv_load_policy=1&amp;start=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;color=red&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

The above iframe has a thumbnail associated with it, which looks like this

```
<div class="poster"><span></span><%# IfImage("Thumbnail",GetBrickImage(Eval("Thumbnail"), "featurevideo", Eval("Title")), "") %></div>
```

and sits just under the closing div of class youtube.

Now my issue is when the users come to the site and presses play on the thumbnail the video doesn't play straight away instead the thumbnail disappears and the default youtube play button appears making the user press play again, when I use the developer tool bar and press play for the first time I get the error

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"
```

I cannot for the life of my figure out what is going wrong, We have recently installed a SSL certificate on the server this site currently sits on and since then its been causing this issue.  From what I have read and see people were suggesting to drop the www. so it would be https://youtube.com....  again this didn't help me.  I then went and tested this on IE10/Chrome and the issue is still happening. Can anyone suggest anything for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a limitation of the CKEditor.  It has been resolved in version 8.2.1.

http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-v8-ckeditor-youtube-embeds-https

Comment: @brendankehren we are currently running the project in version 7, I'm not able to hot fix it so I need to figure out another solution

Comment: @ScottAtkinson if you are currently under a valid maintenance agreement, you could email Kentico Support and ask for an alternative solution for your version (since it is still supported).

Comment: took 8 years to accept the answer... better late than never :)